# multiple conditions in list comprehension python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, list-comprehension

I have a column of prices below which I want to clean in one liner list comprehension in Python

```
Prices
15.90 EUR
17.80 EUR
15,80 EUR
26.10 EUR
44,10 EUR
3A'999,90,,,,,,,,
```

My code:

```
prices = df.Prices 
prices =  [re.findall('\d+.\d+',str(x).replace(',','.'))[0] for x in prices] # It works but not suitable for last price
prices =  [x==re.findall('\d+.\d+',str(x).replace(',','.')) for x in prices if len(x)>0 else None] # Wrong syntax
```

I want that if there is no match it should add `None` and correct price if regex matches. I can do it with long way by using if else or try except but I want to use one liner. Is it possible ?

Comment: Why do you want to use a one liner? It will look way too dense and ugly

Comment: Could you post your desired resulting data set?

Comment: `['15.90', '17.80', '15.80', '26.10', '44.10', None]`. This is the output I can expect from the question. But later I want to clean `3A'999,90,,,,,,,,` to `3999.00` but I have to think about the regex because I don't use regex much.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [35]: df
Out[35]:
      Prices
0  15.90 EUR
1  17.80 EUR
2  15,80 EUR
3  26.10 EUR
4  44,10 EUR
5  3A'999,90
6        333

In [36]: df.dtypes
Out[36]:
Prices    object
dtype: object

In [37]: df['Prices'] = pd.to_numeric(df.Prices.str.replace(',','.')
    ...:                                .str.extract(r'(\d+[\.,]{,1}?\d+?)',
    ...:                                             expand=False),
    ...:                              errors='coerce')

In [38]: df
Out[38]:
   Prices
0    15.9
1    17.8
2    15.8
3    26.1
4    44.1
5   999.9
6   333.0

In [39]: df.dtypes
Out[39]:
Prices    float64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax

```
 prices =  [x==re.findall('\d+.\d+',str(x).replace(',','.')) if len(x)>0 else None for x in prices]
```